# Git pull taking a lot of time & does not execute git pull in Jenkins(Windows)

Tags: git, github, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

Git pull taking a lot of time & does not execute git pull in Jenkins(Windows).
I have the latest Jenkins(2.35) and Git plugin version(3.0.1) but still it doesn't work. Jenkins previous version UI was different where it had more options compared to the latest. Is there any option to fix it?

Comment: I'm sure we even know what needs fixing yet.  Have you verified that your network connection isn't the problem?  Does pulling behave this way for all branches/repos?

Comment: Yes! Git pull works via command line but not working in Jenkins